# java.io.EOFException when trying to run examples on HBase standalone

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I'm trying to run this example: https://github.com/larsgeorge/hbase-book/blob/master/ch03/src/main/java/client/PutExample.java, from this book: http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449396107/, on a standalone HBase installation. Starting HBase works fine and the shell is accessible, but when I try to run the example I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Call to /127.0.0.1:55958 failed on local exception: java.io.EOFException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.wrapException(HBaseClient.java:872)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.call(HBaseClient.java:841)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(WritableRpcEngine.java:141)
        at $Proxy4.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine.getProxy(WritableRpcEngine.java:174)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:295)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:272)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.getProxy(HBaseRPC.java:324)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseRPC.waitForProxy(HBaseRPC.java:228)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getHRegionConnection(HConnectionManager.java:1228)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getHRegionConnection(HConnectionManager.java:1190)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getHRegionConnection(HConnectionManager.java:1177)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(HConnectionManager.java:914)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:810)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.relocateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:784)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegionInMeta(HConnectionManager.java:1014)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:814)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.locateRegion(HConnectionManager.java:778)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:188)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.<init>(HTable.java:159)
        at client.CRUDExample.main(CRUDExample.java:26)
    Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:375)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.receiveResponse(HBaseClient.java:548)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.run(HBaseClient.java:486)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I compiled the examples with a newer version of HBase. To fix this error, for these examples, edit pom.xml and make sure that the HBase dependency is the same version as you're running and build again. (Also don't forget to remove chXX/target/cached_classpath.txt, otherwise it still adds the other library to your classpath)

Comment: Can you explain. I have a pom that has consistent versions, deleted the target output, rebuilt, and still can't get this working.

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem with exactly same error logs, but difference reason.
It is fixed after I added bellow items to hbase client config:

```html
<property>
    <name>hbase.security.authentication</name>
    <value>kerberos</value> 
</property> 
<property>
     <name>hbase.rpc.engine</name>
     <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.SecureRpcEngine</value>
</property>
```